# Unmet dependencies when installing mtrack

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, dependencies

I'm trying to install mtrack on Ubuntu 14.04 on my macbook pro:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack
```

But I get unmet dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 xserver-xorg-input-mtrack : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                         Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/610505/broken-packages-error-while-trying-to-install-xserver-xorg-input-mtrack to no avail.

Edit for the fine gentlemen in the comments:

```
xserver-xorg-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7
  Version table:
     2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-core`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem, having installed the 3.19 (Vivid) kernel on 14.04.

As per the [Ubuntu wiki's LTS Enable Stack page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) you need to:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-core-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-vivid xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-vivid libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid
```

You should then install the Vivid xorg package xserver-xorg-lts-vivid

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-vivid
```

You will then be able to install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack.

Change vivid in all the above to utopic if you have that kernel.